# JSON api filtering in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, next.js

I am new to Coding and I am doing a personal project and I got stuck in api filtering.My requirement is that the data should be rendered if the data in it equals to a specific word for eg:-known_for_department=="Directing" if this is true it should render the data in it.How could do it in reactjs.Can someone help me.

```js
{
            "adult": false,
            "gender": 2,
            "id": 1787802,
            "known_for_department": "Directing",
            "name": "Brian Avery Galligan",
            "original_name": "Brian Avery Galligan",
            "popularity": 0.63,
            "profile_path": null,
            "credit_id": "5fd051d968929c003bc48070",
            "department": "Directing",
            "job": "Second Unit First Assistant Director"
        },
        {
            "adult": false,
            "gender": 1,
            "id": 1774412,
            "known_for_department": "Production",
            "name": "Rachel O'Connor",
            "original_name": "Rachel O'Connor",
            "popularity": 0.6,
            "profile_path": null,
            "credit_id": "6124530a0f2fbd004815b6cb",
            "department": "Production",
            "job": "Executive Producer"
        },
```

this is the api data i have and from this i should filter if known_for_department==directing and if it is true i should render all the items in it the page.Can someone help me.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

A. Create your API requests, based on keywords you need(good)

B. Filter your data on the client-side (bad). In this case your code will be slower

```
let inputData = [
        {
            "adult": false,
            "gender": 2,
            "id": 1787802,
            "known_for_department": "Directing",
            "name": "Brian Avery Galligan",
            "original_name": "Brian Avery Galligan",
            "popularity": 0.63,
            "profile_path": null,
            "credit_id": "5fd051d968929c003bc48070",
            "department": "Directing",
            "job": "Second Unit First Assistant Director"
        },
        {
            "adult": false,
            "gender": 1,
            "id": 1774412,
            "known_for_department": "Production",
            "name": "Rachel O'Connor",
            "original_name": "Rachel O'Connor",
            "popularity": 0.6,
            "profile_path": null,
            "credit_id": "6124530a0f2fbd004815b6cb",
            "department": "Production",
            "job": "Executive Producer"
        },
]

let outputData = []

for (const element of inputData){
    if (element["department"] === "Directing"){
        outputData.push(element)
    }    
}
console.log(outputData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this within your return statement :

```
{known_for_department === directing && <something/> }
```

The expression right of the && operator will only be executed (here: rendered) if the part left of it is truthy.

for instance :

return (

```
{api_data.known_for_department === api_data.directing && ({api_data.map((element) => <p>{element}</p>)}
)
```

This should then render paragraphs for all properties of your api_data.

If you want to render sth different in case the condition is falsy, you can use a ternary operator, like this:

```
{known_for_department === directing ? <something/> : <something_else/> }
```

If you want to only evoke the return statement at all if the condition is truthy, write:

```
if (known_for_department === directing) {
return (something...)
}
```